# Linear regression with binary variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss, categorical-encoding

Good day,

I hope you could help me.

My problem: I'm doing a linear regression with SPSS. Among other things, I am interested in gender differences. Since a distinction is only made between men and women, a binary variable is appropriate.

My main problem:
My results change if I define the binary variable differently.
If I set male = 1, female = 2, the values ​​are different than if I set male = 0 and female = 1.
How can that be? And what is correct?

Thank you & stay healthy

[image]

[image]

The first is with male = 1, female = 2.
The second is with male = 0, female = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary variables like this tend to make the most sense as on/off switches. When the variable is off, consider men. Then switch on the variable to consider women. (Or have “off” be women and turn on the variable to consider men.)

The typical way to do this is is by setting the “off” category as $0$ and the “on” category as $1$. Consequently, I would not give any consideration to the model when you use $1$ and $2$. The $0$ and $1$ model tells you what the differences are between women and men.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply.

So you're saying the reason I'm getting different results is because I'm testing different hypotheses?

With male = 0, female = 1, I test (as always): H0: male = female, H1: male ≠ female.

If male = 1, female = 2, I'm not testing if there is a difference, but something else. 

Right?

An other question: So I HAVE TO use 0 and 1? 1 and 2 are wrong?

Comment: I just thought because the difference (1-0=1 and 2-1=1) is the same in both definitions, the results have to be the same.

Comment: Is `FW_x_Geschlecht` an interaction term with the gender variable? If so, why doesn't `FW` appear on its own? That isn't technically a requirement, but it tends to be advisable. If  `FW_x_Geschlecht` is such an interaction term, then coding as $1$ and $2$ will change the slopes, which means that more than just the intercept changes. // What does it mean that the dpendent variable is `Factor_KI`? That does not make sense to me for a linear model. (There could be an argument, even if just a weak one, for a linear probability model of a binary variable, but not for multiple factor levels.)

Comment: Sorry, here is a little background: 
We are testing the purchase intention (KI, dependent variable) of a food processor as part of a project work. We have different independent variables (Functional Value = FW, Social Value = SW,...).
We take gender as our moderator variable and want to test whether gender via FW or SW, … has an impact on purchase intent (KI).


Added:
Also yes, FW_x_gender is an interaction term. And you are absolutely right, FW has yet to appear alone in the regression. Thank you a lot for telling me!

Comment: Why does KI not make sense to you for a linear model.? Our professor gave our step-by-step instructions to do in SPSS, including the multiple lineare regression.

Comment: What is `KI`? Perhaps it makes sense, but if it is a categorical variable, having `KI` as the outcome of a linear regression is tough to defend for much beyond learning the mechanics of doing regression in a software package.

Comment: We asked about purchase intention (KI) using 4 items, which the test person then had to rate using the Likert scale (0-6). We then formed an average value (over these 4 items) for each test person. As a result, KI consists of 190 means (since 190 test persons).

What do you think? Critical? 

Best regards!

Comment: There are probably better ways to do it, but that is at least okay. Calling it a factor, however, is misleading, since it is a number, not a factor level.

Comment: Thank you! And greetings from Germany to wherever you live.

Comment: Hello, Earthling ;)

Comment: The best way would be to specify factor (nominal, categorical) variables as such, instead of trying to code them as numeric. A quick internet search seems to indicate that SPSS cannot not do this, because there are tutorials how to manually create dummy variables for factor variables. I hardly believe this, because factor variables are quite common, so I would guess that SPSS has a built in way to deal with them.